# Using REST API for bulk stock upload and pushing these to RabbitMQ queue for asynchronous processing?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq

We have REST POST API /api/{sellerId}/products. This is used by sellers to bulk upload their stocks into our system.

Since we do not limit the number of stocks and do not want clients to wait for a response, we send back HTTP202 status while pushing these stocks to RabbitMq.

But I was wondering that here we are making double serialization/deserialization,

1. Once when the client pushes bulk JSON request to our system using HTTP POST interface.
2. Then, once HTTP POST API push this bulk request to rabbitmq system.

How can we optimize this? What is more standard/better approach to do this? Can we directly let clients push Rabbitmq message instead of exposing HTTP API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming the client is using a web application to securely access and upload their inventory stocks. To skip the double serialization, you will need to..
1. Put your rabbitMQ on the internet (probably a separate server)
2. Probably create a windows application (Producer) that will produce to the queue.

However, this will open up two main things.
1. Security issues, as anyone with knowledge can actually produce any messages to your rabbitMQ and thereby compromise your platform, if not data.
2. Upgrades or updates to the windows application over a number of clients could be a challenge and add a support layer/topic to your product.

The current scenario is ideal, as any updates to the Logic or BI will not really be reflected out to the client and secondly, your HTTP API can be doubled up as a security and check layer for the messages being queues.